# In iOS, can I access the iTunes song list?

Tags: ios, itunes

I'm looking for a way to programmatically (*i.e.*, not via UI) access a users iTunes music library from my iOS app.

(Yes, I am aware that Apple discourages alternate iPod-interface apps.  That's not the question :)

What I'd like to do is:

> - Gather a list of song names.
> - Have my app make an anagram of them.
> - Have the user guess the original song name.
> - If they guess right, I play a snippet of the song.

(That's not my real application, but it contains all the pieces I need.)  The parts that I'm asking about are: How to get a list of song names and, given a song name, how to get the media to play it?

I think that AVAssetReader is what will let me play a song, once I have its name, so I can look that up on my own (bonus points for pointers there, though!) -- so the bottom-line question is: How to get a list of song titles from a user's iTunes Library in iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use MPMediaQuery to get an NSArray of all the songs. Check out [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) link.

To play the song, I would suggest using AVPlayer.

Answer (score 5):

[Check out the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9), especially the section titled "Getting Media Items Programmatically".

> If the media item picker doesn’t provide the control you want, you can
>   use the database access classes from this API. These classes are
>   designed to let you create arbitrarily complex queries. You could, for
>   example, retrieve all the songs in a particular genre whose titles
>   include a particular word or phrase.
>
> Using programmatic access is a two step process:
>
> Configure a query. Ask the query to retrieve its matching media items.
>   A media query is a description of what to retrieve from the device
>   iPod library and how those retrieved items should be arranged. It has
>   two properties to configure:
>
> The filter is the description of what to retrieve. The filter is
>   optional; a filterless query matches the entire iPod library. The
>   grouping type is an optional key that specifies the arrangement to use
>   for retrieved collections of media items. Zooming in a bit more, the
>   filter can be as simple or complex as your application demands. It
>   consists of one or more instances of a media property predicate. A
>   media property predicate is a statement of a logical condition to test
>   each media item against. The items that satisfy the filter are
>   retrieved from the iPod library when you invoke the query.
>
> The optional grouping type specifies the arrangement and sorting of
>   collections as well as the sorting of media items within each
>   collection. For example, using an “album” grouping type results in
>   returned media items grouped by album, with each album’s songs sorted
>   in track order.

Comment: The link is Broken.